# naming convention for business logic layer these days?

Tags: c#

Several years ago, it was pretty standard for the Data Access Layer to be in its own project named DAL.  I've noticed a trend in the last few years where this project is instead named Repository.

Several years ago, it was pretty standard for the Business Logic Layer to be in its own project named BLL.  Is this still a common convention or have devs moved to some other name for this project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a standard, really.  I take much of my architecture approach from DDD, and thus call it the Domain layer, so `ProjectName.Domain` is what I wind up with.  Core is another that I see often: `ProjectName.Core`, or sometimes just `ProjectName.Models`

I tend to think this really depends on the architecture approach you're using.  Depending on how your projects are layed out and structured, it may make more sense to use some other name for it.  In a traditional 3-tier architecture, `BLL` is still fine.  Just make it semantic and follow a consistent convention within your projects and you'll be fine.